# Can't login into ubuntu, weird keyboard bug

Tags: login, keyboard-layout

So, I just installed ubuntu into my old laptop and I'm currently in the login screen but every character I type it gets a ^ before it (H is ^H for example), also backspace types ^H and sometimes it clears the screen. That is blocking me from logging in, the weird thing is that sometimes it works fine. I dont know if the keyboard is broken because I dont have any spare keyboard to test it and I would like to avoid having to disconnect mine.

Comment: Try another keyboard to be sure!

Comment: Changing `H` to `^H` (and probably `L` to `^L`) indicates a 1-bit failure in your keyboard/keyboard connection. Replace your keyboard.

Comment: I tried another keyboard and it worked, but since I have only this keyboard wich I use on my main PC is there any way to fix it? Maybe auto-login since the keyboard works fine in the terminal

Comment: Your **control** key is stuck in the down/pressed condition. Remove the keycap and clean any dirt from around the key stem or scissors adapter. Otherwise replace the keyboard.

Comment: It somehow got fixed, after I connected another keyboard and used it for some time then everything got working